# Using numpy to apply logical xor on a list

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I want to XOR the values in array using `numpy`. When using:

`numpy.logical_xor([1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1])`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 44, in <module>
    print np.logical_xor([1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1])
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

It seems `numpy` does not accept more than 2 elements in an array. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the reduction method. So, use -

```
np.logical_xor.reduce([1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1])
```

Comment: 15x faster than `np.all(np.logical_xor(a[1:], np.roll(a,1)[1:]))`